# SQL parent/child sum values of final childs

Tags: sql

This is my plain table

```
PARENT CHILD QTY
-----------------
A      B     1
A      C     2
A      D     1
B      E     1
B      F     1
E      F     1
A      E     1
```

The expected output is looking like that

```
CHILD    SUM(QTY)
C        2
D        1
F        6
```

Query should be summing all the quantity of "last childs" that means if A parent have B child and B is parent that means hierarchy

```
Aparent -> Bchild -> Bparent
```

then F is last CHILD (no parent) and Echild of `B -> Eparent -> Fchild + 1`. So this is like F QTY1 2times from this disintegration.

Summing whole plain table means C QTY 2, D QTY 1, and F QTY 6times 1.

I found lot of similar questions, but this thinking is so complex for me that it is hard to understand.

This is some combination of hierarchy and recursive. Thanks for your ideas

EDIT logic explanation(C and D is just for essence here):

C QTY is get by A->C = QTY 2
D QTY is get by A->D = QTY 1

then

`A -> Bchild -> Bparent` which split into:

Echild -> Eparent -> Fchild = QTY 1 +
Fchild = QTY 1 (it is 2 so far, then the same disintegration makes F qty 6, the logic is - IF CHILD is in PARENT then count CHILD QTY,but if CHILD is in PARENT then count IT'S CHILD until no Parent named CHILD is found.

EDIT: See SQLFiddle
[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f27eef/1)
This is query to get the expected result but w/o the recursive part...

Comment: you'd need a self-left join, `on main.child = child.parent where child.parent is null`. that'd get all of your "terminal" children.

Comment: What database are the data stored in here? Many DBMSes support recursive queries, but the syntax is very different between i.e. Oracle and Postgres.

Comment: Can you clarify the logic of how `F` gets `6`?  I don't follow your current explanation.

Comment: edited, hope it helped you

Comment: *IF CHILD is in PARENT then count CHILD QTY,but if CHILD is in PARENT* ... this is a bit unclear, at least to me.

Comment: So which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this as an answer to get some more markup.
Here's how F could be 6:

```
F is child of E -> (E-F) = 1
E is child of B -> (B-E) = 1 
B is child of A -> (A-B) = 1

E is child of A -> (A-E) = 1
F is child of B -> (B-F) = 1
B is child of A -> (A-B) = 1
```

Total (E-F) + (B-E) + (A-E) + (B-F) + (A-B) + (A-B) = 6

edit: I think you'll need a function to this. the function would then return the value given a parent. as long as the function returns a value, loop through the results.